# Get a Sub String starting from a certain character of a long string.

Tags: php, string

am having a problem of getting a sub string starting from a certain character of my long string. but i'm having a string that i don't want.

**here is my string**

```
$school_title =   BANGATA PRIMARY SCHOOL - P0101001
```

i want to get this part  **P0101001**

**what i have done**

```
$index_num = stristr($school_title,"- P",false);
```

this function output this **- P0101001**

i want **' - '** to be excluded.

how can i do this?

Comment: `$index_num = explode('- ', $school_title, 2)[1];`

Comment: simple use `$index_num  = trim($index_num ,'-') or ltrim($index_num ,'-')` in the final step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$school_title = 'BANGATA PRIMARY SCHOOL - P0101001';
$index_num = substr($school_title, strpos($school_title, "- P") + 2);

echo $index_num; //P0101001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$temp = explode("- ", $school_title); // split the string
$result = temp[count(temp)-1]; // get the last occurence
echo result; // your result
```

Answer (score 0):

use substr function.

```
$pos = strpos($school_title, '- P'); // find '- P'
$result = substr($school_title, $pos + 2);
```

$pos + 2 is the position of letter P.